# XCODE: UIView background not appearing on screen, even though I set color in storyboard and programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, background-color

I have a UIView that I put into my viewController, just to organize a bit, and I am trying to set the background color to this custom blue that I have. I have set the background color in the identity inspector and programmatically:

```
searchRadiusView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.00859087177, green: 0.09247856156, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
```

I set that in my viewDidLoad. Here is a picture of the storyboard, which is showing the UIView background as the correct color:

[image]

Here is what the view looks like in my simulator:

[image]

Just to clarify, the blue color behind the 'Search Radius (mi.)' label is just the label background color. Any idea why the view is not showing the color and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: It looks like there issue in your constraints.

Comment: if its red that means theres a problem? is there a way to identify the problem?

Comment: I thinks that centerX, centerY constraints were needed.

Comment: where do I set those constraints?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this UIView gave me so many constraint errors (I'm new to UIViews, so maybe this is typical), but I decided to just give every element inside the view a constant width and height, and pin each of the four sides with the distance they were at.  Then I set the constraint of the actual UIView that I wanted, and all the errors went away and my color appeared.  I had to keep everything constant for some reason, which will stop the size of the view from changing depending on the phone type.  That could be a good thing or bad thing depending on how you look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Auto layout constraints in a Storyboard (or for those working in Xcode long enough, IB). Also, you can do it through straight code.

Two things to remember.

- **All** views need two things - size and position.

Position can be relative to the screen or another view, and is usually described in "X and Y terms. But they can be everything from top, bottom, leading, trailing, center X, and center Y. As long as you've define a **unique** X/Y point for the view (emphasis on *unique*) the layout engine will know *where* to place it.

- **Some** views have intrinsic size.

Size is (obviously) width and height. Let's take three types of views. A text field, a label, and a slider. A text field needs a clearly defined width and height. A slider needs a width, but you really cannot give it a height. These two are pretty easy to see.

It's labels (and sometimes buttons) that can be harder to grasp when you are just learning auto layout. They have what is called *intrinsic* size.

Say you have a label with the text set to "Hello world!". Let's say the font is a system font set to 12 points. That label needs a layout *position*, but it *does not* need a size. The system will decide it - and dynamically change it based on to user settings.

As a developer, you have several things you can do. Obviously, you can dictate the font size, which will (a) prevent the OS or DynamicType from changing things - but this doesn't change the intrinsic size. That's the other thing you can do - set a height and width through constraints.

If that's the only thing you do - set the size but not the font - then the label will truncate things if the font the user select in the OS is too large.

But in the end, you need to set two **unique** things with your constraints - size and position.